# Проблема json_decode в PHP

Tags: php, json

Столкнулся с такой проблемкой.
Функция **json_decode** в php не отрабатывает.

В то время, если файл запросить через jquery:

```
$.post('txt.json',function(arr){console.log(arr);},'json');
```

то там он как положено обрабатывается.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема, почему PHP не может распознать в нем json и раскодировать в массив/объект

Comment: _"unexpected character"_ © `json_last_error_msg`

Comment: А как-то вычислить в каком именно символе(ах) проблема можно?
Мог бы удалять такие символы перед декодированием replace

Comment: Эврика! Я понял! Проблема была в том, что файл был в кодировке UTF-8-BOM
Сохранил в UTF-8 и все стало ок

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что файл был в кодировке UTF-8-BOM Сохранил в UTF-8 и все стало ок